# I´m trying to process a pcap file using Java to extract every field into a CSV file

Tags: java, export-to-csv, pcap

I'm trying to extract every piece of information that the pcap file have and parse it into a CSV but I dont get all the fields I need from the study I want to do. Does anybody know how to extract every field using Java?

I've already tried using the `pkts` library and the `jnetpcap` library. Now I'm trying with an Internet example.

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    final Pcap pcap = Pcap.openStream("prueba.pcap");

    pcap.loop(new PacketHandler() {

        public boolean nextPacket(Packet packet) throws IOException {


            if (packet.hasProtocol(Protocol.TCP)) {

                TCPPacket tcpPacket = (TCPPacket) packet.getPacket(Protocol.TCP);
                Buffer buffer = tcpPacket.getPayload();
                if (buffer != null) {
                    System.out.println("TCP: " + buffer);
                }
            } else if (packet.hasProtocol(Protocol.UDP)) {

                UDPPacket udpPacket = (UDPPacket) packet.getPacket(Protocol.UDP);
                Buffer buffer = udpPacket.getPayload();
                if (buffer != null) {
                    System.out.println("UDP: " + buffer);
                }
            }            

            return true;
        }
    });
  }
}
```

I want a proccesed file with all the info to train a model with traffic.

Comment: What fields do you need? I don't think there is a way to dump all possible fields, you have to extract those you want.

Comment: And does it have to be java? There is already a utility for making a csv out of pcap, just supply a list of fields...: https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/2935/creating-a-csv-file-with-tshark

Comment: @jakub_d  The "info" field more precisely is plain text and I need to be a CSV file for all parameters. I use Java because I feel confident in it.

Comment: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.pkts/pkts-core/3.0.4 <- pkts doesn't seem to have a field called "info", so I'm not sure what you are looking for

Comment: @jakub_d Here is the thing, I want all possible information that Wireshark can display for every packet processed into a CSV file for a study. One of the filelds that pcap displays is and Info field wich is plain text and it doesnt even get display using the library. So I dont know if I should use a really long tshark command or what.

Comment: The Info field in Wireshark is the result of Wireshark recognizing the protocol, using the protocol-specific plugin on the packet and that plugin printing as much information about the packet as it can in free-form text. So to get that, you actually need Wireshark and all its plugins (java library for dealing with pcap format is not going to help you, you want specifically a wireshark feature). Or tshark, which is its alternate frontend.

Comment: What you can do in java afterwards is taking apart the Info field to extract some details out of that text. But it depends on the speciifc plugin and the information it prints.

Comment: @jakub_d And how do I extract that info if its a plain text?

Comment: Let's look at some examples: "DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x18dd76f",   "RST. Root = 32768/0/00:12:34:56:78:9a  Cost = 20000  Port = 0x8042",  "M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1 " - three packets, different information in different formats. I don't have general advice how to get "all possible information that Wireshark can display for every packet processed into a CSV file". You can certainly find some interesting packets in your own captures and write specific code to extract some information you like from them.

Comment: For advice on parsing text, search for "parsing text" or "regular expressions".